# Generate a bicubic ellipsoid in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, ellipse

I need to generate a bicubic ellipsoid, for which I've tried to set up the parametric equation of an ellipsoid in mathematica like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{4 Sin[u] Cos[v], 3 Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u]}, {u, 0,
Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False, Background -> Black, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

My problem is that since I need a bicubic surface, I want to limit this parametric plot to 16 points and I cant figure out how to make mathematica sample only the number of points I need.I'm a newbie to both mathematica and geometric modeling.

Comment: Do your just want the points? If so then perhaps this: Graphics3D[ Map[ Point, Union[ Flatten[ Table[{4 Sin[u] Cos[v], 3 Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u]}, {u,0,Pi,Pi/3}, {v,0,2 Pi,Pi/3}],1]]]] If you want more than that then perhaps a more detailed explanation might help.

Comment: Thanks @Bill , thats what I was looking for. But this generates only 14 points, while I was looking for a way to generate the 16 control points required for the patch.

Comment: Using something smaller than Pi/3 for each iterator will give you more points. Pi/3 and Pi/4 gives you 18 points or Pi/6 and Pi/6 will give you 62 points. I can't guess what you really need for this.

Comment: Perhaps Table[{4 Sin[u] Cos[v], 3 Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u]}, {u,0,Pi-Pi/4,Pi/4}, {v,0,2 Pi-Pi/2,Pi/2}] which gives you 16 points, but some of those points are the same.

Comment: Thanks @Bill. I was able to figure out how to generate the points I need based on your help.